# Changing the theme of an android app using preferences

Tags: android

I have been trying to get my app to read data from the preferences, and change the theme according to the option selected. I have found many different suggestions on the internet, including here, but have been unable to get it to work.

I have created preferences.xml and arrays.xml, and the user is able to select the theme they want. However, the change is not reflected in the app.

Here are the contents of ActivityMain.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String userTheme = preferences.getString("prefTheme", "darkab"); 
    if (userTheme.equals("darkab"))
        setTheme(R.style.darkab);
    else if (userTheme.equals("light"))
        setTheme(R.style.light);
    else if (userTheme.equals("dark"))
        setTheme(R.style.dark);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    recreate();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String userTheme = preferences.getString("prefTheme", "darkab");
    if (userTheme.equals("darkab"))
        setTheme(R.style.darkab);
    else if (userTheme.equals("light"))
        setTheme(R.style.light);
    else {setTheme(R.style.dark);}
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

These are the styles I wish to use, as set in styles.xml:

```
<style name="darkab" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
<style name="light" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"></style>
<style name="dark" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
```

And here is my preferences.java file:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTheme()` is effective *only before* the layout has been constructed i.e. you should call it before `setContentView()`. The `LayoutInflater` resolves theme attributes and accordingly set properties on the `View`'s it creates. To apply a theme on an already running Activity, you would have to re-start the Activity.

Comment: setTheme() is before setContentView() isn't it?

To restart the activity, do I need to put recreate() in the onResume section?

Comment: @CarlAnsell Make `setTheme()` the first statement in `onCreate()`. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4394

Comment: Thanks, it is now working. However, it only works when pressing an in app back button, not the system back button. I've updated the code I'm using in the OP.

Answer (score -1):

I know that I am late but I would like to post a solution here:
Check the full source code [here.](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/10/implementing-users-choice-themeapply.html)
This is the code I used when changing theme using preferences..

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String themeName = pref.getString("prefSyncFrequency3", "Theme1");
if (themeName.equals("Africa")) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
} else if (themeName.equals("Colorful Beach")) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "set theme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setTheme(R.style.beach);
} else if (themeName.equals("Abstract")) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "set theme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setTheme(R.style.abstract2);
} else if (themeName.equals("Default")) {
    setTheme(R.style.defaulttheme);
}
```

Please note that you have to put the code before setcontentview..

Comment: Please don't post the same answer to multiple questions. If the questions are duplicates, then post an answer to the best question and flag the other questions as duplicate of the best one. If they are not duplicates, then you need to adjust every answer in order to answer that specific question. Also, please try to get the formatting right and [don't include](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/266187) "HAPPY CODING" in each and every answer of yours.